# Trouble with Emacs Tramp when trying to sudo access remote file

Tags: emacs, sudo, tramp

In Emacs25 I used the recommended syntax to open a remote file in sudo mode:

`find-file "/ssh:ichiban@izu|sudo:ichiban@izu:~/`

but Emacs just hangs.  I set some degging settings in my .emacs file:

```
(require 'tramp)
;(setq tramp-debug-buffer t)
(setq tramp-verbose 10)

; to enable tracing in tramp
(require 'trace)
(dolist (elt (all-completions "tramp-" obarray 'functionp))
  (trace-function-background (intern elt)))
(untrace-function 'tramp-read-passwd)
(untrace-function 'tramp-gw-basic-authentication)
```

but the resultant information is no help.

To see that information I start Emacs from a terminal and then send it a Ctrl-c (without a return) from the terminal when it hangs - then I can read the debug data.

Without sudo mode it works fine:

`find-file "/ssh:ichiban@izu:~/`

I'd like to see more detail about the protocol Emacs is using and also learn how to tweak that protocol - **any ideas would be appreciated.**

This is where the debug outputs for the "sudo" and "non sudo" cases differ:

fail: **sudo case** /ssh:ichiban@izu|sudo:ichiban@izu:/home/ichiban

```
15:12:54.224210 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Opening connection for ichiban@izu using sudo...
15:12:54.240334 tramp-get-local-locale (7) # locale en_US.utf8
15:12:54.240731 tramp-compute-multi-hops (5) # Add proxy ("izu" "ichiban" "/ssh:ichiban@izu:")
15:13:08.214197 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Opening connection for ichiban@izu using sudo...failed
```

succcess :**non sudo case** /ssh:ichiban@izu:/home/ichiban

```
15:02:58.629883 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Opening connection for ichiban@izu using ssh...
15:02:58.647868 tramp-get-local-locale (7) # locale en_US.utf8
15:02:58.648444 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # login-args undef
15:02:58.648777 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # login-args undef
15:02:58.649111 tramp-call-process (6) # ‘ssh -o ControlMaster’ nil  *temp*
15:02:58.651325 tramp-call-process (6) # 255
command-line line 0: missing argument.
15:02:58.651640 tramp-call-process (6) # ‘ssh -o ControlPath=%C 0.0.0.1’ nil  *temp*
15:02:58.655076 tramp-call-process (6) # 255
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> find-file "/ssh:ichiban@izu|sudo:ichiban@izu:~/
> ```

You almost certainly wanted to use:

```
find-file "/ssh:ichiban@izu|sudo:root@izu:~/
```

or equivalently (as root is the default user for this method) and shorter:

```
find-file "/ssh:ichiban@izu|sudo:izu:~/
```

I'm going to hazard a guess that Emacs was hanging because tramp was in an infinite loop trying to resolve the proxy you'd given it -- you'd told it to use the proxy `/ssh:ichiban@izu:` when accessing files as `ichiban@izu`!

Please `M-x report-emacs-bug` to suggest that some cycle detection is added to protect against this.

Comment: As specified here: [ https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode#toc18  ], I was using the syntax:  [ C-x C-f /ssh:you@remotehost|sudo:them@remotehost:/path/to/file RET ] except that "them" is "you".  In terms of actions, 1:[connect to ichiban@izu via ssh] , then 2:[elevate ichiban to sudo].  
I will try your suggestion.

Comment: OK, it works!  The password I enter is ichiban's password, not root's, which is what I wanted.  Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that the tramp syntax is much like using the `sudo` command from a shell: `/sudo:root@host` is like running `sudo -u root <command>`, which is the same as running just `sudo <command>`.  So your original attempt was equivalent to first logging in as `ichiban` and then issuing the shell command `sudo -u ichiban <command>` to run `<command>` as the user `ichiban`, despite already being logged in as that user.